# Processing a remote iCal with Python

Tags: python, http, icalendar

Hi I need to process a remote .ical file from another server on my own server and hand it back to the requesting user.

So what I need to do is:

- Fetch the file (could do this with urllib2)
- Process the file with some regex (not the question)
- hand it back with a specific header <-- *my main problem*

I'd know how to do this with php:

```
header('Content-type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=calendar.ics');
echo $ical;
exit;
```

But how to do the same thing in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as with anything web-related, you start with [a WSGI application](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/).

```
def app(environ, start_response):
    calendar = get_processed_file()

    start_response('200 OK', [
        ('Content-Type', 'text/icalendar; charset=utf-8'),
        ('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename=calendar.ics'),
    ])
    yield calendar
```

Then to deploy, you use a handler, e.g. plain CGI would be

```
import wsgiref
wsgiref.CGIHandler().run(app)
```

See http://www.wsgi.org/ for more materials about WSGI.